# Cannot import PDF with JPXDecode or JBIG2Decode Filters?

Tags: import, pdf-format

I am trying to what I think should be a very basic thing, which is to import a large PDF from my files into Mathematica. The long term goal is to extract images from the PDF. The original command was

```
Import["Users/carlaj/Documents/Laurel/jotb.pdf"];
```

And that didn't work. It said that the filters were unknown (JBIG2Decode, and JPXDecode), and that:

```
LinkObject::linkd: "Unable to communicate with closed link \!\(LinkObject[\"'/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Converters/Binaries/MacOSX-x86-64/PDF.exe'\", 4465, 12]\). "
```

So I tested that it could, in fact, import from this file location and wrote:

```
Import["Users/carlaj/Documents/Laurel/jotbocr.txt"];
```

Which worked fine.

So, I tried importing a few other files, one from the same folder, "Laurel", one from the internet, and one from a different folder. None of these worked, but for different reasons. Basically it would appear that it won't import PDFs. See the image for various complications.

[image: Failed PDF imports, plus detailed feedback]

What do you think is going on? I'm pretty new to Mathematica, so it's totally possible I'm making a mistake, but I don't understand what's going on.

Here is a URL to one of the PDFs that isn't working: http://ia802702.us.archive.org/9/items/jockofthebushveld00fitziala/jockofthebushveld00fitziala.pdf

This is the online version, and the saved version is the one that I am working with.

Comment: Mathematica doesn't handle every PDF document.  It usually helps to convert the PDF to an older version format, or to just re-process it through some tool you have available (Acrobat, OS X Preview, Ghostscript, mupdf, xpdf can all be useful).

Comment: Please share at least some of the problematic PDFs in order to allow us to experiment with them.

Comment: I added a link in the original post, hopefully that helps.

I will try to reprocess it through OS X Preview or something and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Your PDF is a scanned and OCR'ed version of a printed book. Are you sure it is a good idea to import it into *Mathematica*? If you need to process scanned images, I would suggest to export them from the PDF as TIFF files (you can do this using Acrobat or free `pdfimages` utility from Poppler) and then process TIFF files in *Mathematica*.

Comment: So, sort of for practicing purposes I wanted to extract the images from throughout the text, but I do also need the images. I will try exporting them as TIFF files, thanks.

Comment: Note also that in your PDF the scanned color images are converted into  stacks of layers each encoded either as JPEG2000 (which *Mathematica* can import) or as JBIG2 (unsupported by *Mathematica*). So the simplest solution would be to use Acrobat which can automatically merge them into single TIFF files (`pdfimages` extracts layers as separate files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PDF is a scanned and OCR'ed version of a printed book created by LuraTech PDF Compressor. If you need to process scanned images, I would suggest to export them from the PDF as TIFF files (you can do this using Acrobat or free `pdfimages` utility from Poppler) and then process TIFF files in *Mathematica*.

Note also that in your PDF the scanned color images are converted into stacks of layers each encoded either as JPEG2000 (which *Mathematica* can import) or as JBIG2 (unsupported by *Mathematica*). So the simplest solution is to use Acrobat which will automatically merge them into single TIFF files (`pdfimages` extracts layers as separate files).

Comment: Okay! I have imported it as a TIFF after converting it in OS X Preview. I also successfully imported a plain text version available on BHL.